# Como fixar a posição final de um texrtField após um PanGesture

Tags: uitextfield

Estou com um probleminha no meu código.
Eu tenho uma view com dois textFields, um na parte superior e outro na inferior, ambos sobre uma imageView.
Adicionei uma função PanGesture para permitir a movimentação desses textFields após o carregamento de uma imagem. Permitindo que seja posicionado o texto sobre a imagem no local que o usuário escolher.
O problema é que após usar o PanGesture e reposicionar os textFields, o usuário pode compartilhar a nova imagem por meio de uma ActivityView, no entanto, quando a activityView aparece os textFields voltam para a posição original, como se a view fosse reinicializada.
Como posso fixar os textfields nas novas posições finais? O que estou fazendo de errado ou deixando de fazer? Preciso mexer nas constraints?
Segue as partes do meu código para facilitar o entendimento...

```
//MARK: - PAN GESTURE RECOGNIZER

//Permiti a movimentação do textField superior por gesto.
@IBAction func didPanTfTop(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)

    if sender.state == .began {
        print("Gesture began")
        textFieldOriginalCenter = tfTop.center
    } else if sender.state == .changed {
        print("Gesture is changed")
        tfTop.center = CGPoint(x: textFieldOriginalCenter.x + translation.x, y: textFieldOriginalCenter.y + translation.y)
    } else if sender.state == .ended {
        print("Gesture ended")

    }
}

//Permiti a movimentação do textField inferior por gesto.
@IBAction func didPanTfBottom(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)

    if sender.state == .began {
        print("Gesture began")
        textFieldOriginalCenter = tfBottom.center
    } else if sender.state == .changed {
        print("Gesture is changed")
        tfBottom.center = CGPoint(x: textFieldOriginalCenter.x + translation.x, y: textFieldOriginalCenter.y + translation.y)
    } else if sender.state == .ended {
        print("Gesture ended")

    }
}
```

}

Aqui segue a activityView

```
    //Aciona uma activeView para compartilhar o Meme
@IBAction func share(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    Feedback.share.hapticFeedback()
    let memeImage = generateMemedImage()
    let activityView = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [memeImage], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityView.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) -> Void in

        if completed {
            self.save()
            print("Image has saved")
        }
    }
    present(activityView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na versão em inglês recebi a resposta do amigo Rob Ryan, a qual transcrevo aqui...

1- primeiro precisamos criar os outlets das Constraints

```
//TOP TextField Constraints outlets
@IBOutlet weak var topUpConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var topRightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var topLeftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

//BOTTOM TextField Constraints outlets
@IBOutlet weak var bottomDownConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomRightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomLeftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

2- Para o textField superior vamos apresentar uma solução simples, embora tenha alguma fragilidade

```
    //Solução simplificada, mas um pouco frágil, que permiti a movimentação do textField superior por gesto.

@IBAction func didPanTfTop(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            originalTransform = gesture.view!.transform
        case .changed, .ended:
            let translation = gesture.translation(in: gesture.view)
            gesture.view?.transform = originalTransform.translatedBy(x: translation.x, y: translation.y)
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

3- Para o textField inferior vamos apresentar uma solução mais complexa e robusta.

```
  //Solução mais robusta e segura que permiti a movimentação do textField inferior por gesto.
@IBAction func didPanTfBottom(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            originalBottomDownConstant = bottomDownConstraint.constant
            originalBottomRightConstant = bottomRightConstraint.constant
            originalBottomLeftConstant = bottomLeftConstraint.constant
        case .changed, .ended:
            let translation = gesture.translation(in: gesture.view)
            bottomDownConstraint.constant = originalBottomDownConstant + translation.y
            bottomRightConstraint.constant = originalBottomRightConstant + translation.x
            bottomLeftConstraint.constant = originalBottomLeftConstant + translation.x
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

É isso... Dessa forma fixamos os textFields após o UIPanGestureReconizer